# Use Ajax from mobile to call JSON from RAILS 3 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, http, mobile

I'm trying to send an ajax request to my server from a common html file (to be loaded on mobile) and am having some issues here.

If I use RestClient, from WizTools i can easily create a json POST command with body `{"email":"myemail", "password":"mypassword"}`, and setting headers `"Content-type":"application/json"` and `"Accept":"application/json"`.

But from the Browser when i add the contentType, it just sends an OPTIONS method instead of POST, and the server is expecting a POST. If i take the contentType tag out, the request goes ok with a POST, but the server does not recognize it as JSON, and so blocks the request.

Why does this happen? How can I solve this and list the user's data ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

function runAjax() {
var url_p = "https://myserver/list";
var emailVal = "email@email.com"
var passwordVal = "mypwd"

  $.ajax({
type: 'POST', 
url: url_p,
dataType: "application/json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

data: { "email": emailVal, "password": passwordVal },
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                            $("#result").html(data);
        },
error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  
               if(jqXHR.status&&jqXHR.status==400){
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
               }else{
                   alert("Something went wrong");
               }
          }, 
dataType: "json"
});
}


function resetValue(){
        $("#result").html("");
    }

</script>


</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="runAjax()">Post Ajax call</button>
    <button onclick="resetValue()">Reset value</button>
    <p>Result</p>
    <p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

This seems to be the Cross-domain problem with Ajax. I've since tried to use jsonp as data- type but then HTTP goes with a GET request instead of POST...

I've seen that in 2010 it wasn't possible to use POST with jsonp across domains...I wonder if it is now..

**EDIT 2**

I ended up using this ajax code (credits to Pedro Carmona)  :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    function rpc_call(){
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://yourserver/list";
        var params = "email=Useremail&password=pwd";

        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                $("#resposta").html(http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.send(params);

    }
    function apagaConteudo(){
        $("#resposta").html("");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="rpc_call()">Post Ajax call</button>
    <button onclick="apagaConteudo()">Apagar conteudo</button>
    <p>Resposta</p>
    <p id="resposta">____Cena______</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a harsh one, but now is finally solved with CORS.

Thank you Tom for the [post](http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428), Forrest Zeisler for your comment there, and Sam for your post [here](http://codeodor.com/index.cfm/2011/7/26/Responding-to-the-OPTIONS-HTTP-method-request-in-Rails-Getting-around-the-Same-Origin-Policy/3387)

Add this line to your routes file

```
match '/list', to: 'things#options', via: :options
```

this to your "things" controller :

```
def options

    render text:""

end
```

and

Add these lines to application_controller.rb file

```
...
before_filter :cors_preflight_check
after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers
...
def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'content-type, accept'

  end

  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == :options
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, X-CSRF-Token'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
  end
```